# Installing fonts for CMD

Tags: windows, cmd, fonts, windows-10

I tried to look online but couldn't find any real solution **on  how to install fonts to windows CMD.** I found some videos on youtube and some tutorials on google but none seem to have worked. I want to install a 3D Unicode font for CMD so I can display other language characters. I tried installing fonts via registry editor but it didn't work... **can anybody help me on how to do this probably very simple task?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To install a font in Windows you drag it into the Fonts folder. CMD can ONLY use fixed width characters.

Comment: Did you see https://superuser.com/q/390933 ?

Comment: Thanks Mark Ransom, I followed your link and it fixed it. I wish you had an answer so I would choose your reply as an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the new Windows Terminal? It comes with a Unicode font and can run in CMD mode

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701